# Query multiple RowKeys in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

[This post from 2010 says](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/d7765773-74b8-4860-b07c-b9731a2210c7/performance-of-range-queries-on-partition-keys-and-row-keys)

```
Query7: PartitionKey == "A" and (RowKey == "A" or RowKey == “F”) 
This results in scanning the entire Partition "A".
```

Is this still the case for the current version of Azure?

Should I prefer two parallel queries or the syntax above when my partition contains only ~20 rows?

Comment: I haven't heard about any changes. The best way would be to test it. Create a big partition (maybe 10k or 100k rows) and time the query each way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer from [Joe Giardino, Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/5160b393-6f40-4354-86a0-8357cb6cf5d6/best-way-to-select-different-unrelated-records-using-rowkey):

> If you want several non contiguous row keys, then issuing separate but
>   parallel individual queries of below form will perform better. When
>   you specify both PartitionKey and RowKey the query is considered a
>   "PointQuery" which is the most performant option.

```
 a) PartitionKey == “MyPK” && RowKey == “FirstRK”
 b) PartitionKey == “MyPK” && RowKey == “SecondRK"
```